# Google Data Studio - How would I visualize orders (something with distinct)

Tags: sql, looker-studio

My dataset looks like this (simplified):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| order-id | SKU | SKU Price | Order Total | Date | Quantity |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 11       | 01  | 10.00     | 25.00       | ...  | 1
| 11       | 02  | 15.00     | 25.00       | ...  | 1
| 12       | 01  | 10.00     | 10.00       | ...  | 1
| 13       | 01  | 10.00     | 35.00       | ...  | 2
| 13       | 02  | 15.00     | 35.00       | ...  | 1
| 14       | 01  | 10.00     | 15.00       | ...  | 1
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to draw a chart: on the x Axis the time and then on Y-Axis the sum of all orders. So basically: "How much do I sell per day". I guess it would have to be something with Distinct, but I have no clue how to do this in Google Data Studio.

Update: Added Quantity and Orders 13 and 14. Order 14 would include 5.00 for shipping that is obviously not included in the Quantity x SKU Price.

Comment: I'd say you want something with GROUP BY.

Comment: group by order-id? ... but how would I implement this in Google Data Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update: Daily `SKU Price`

This does the trick:

- ***Dimension***: `Date`
- ***Metric***: `SKU Price` (Aggregation: [SUM](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212))

A GIF to demonstrate:

[image]

### Original Post

One way it can be achieved is by using a [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) Chart; use #1 or #2 based on the requirement:

**1) Daily `Order Total`**

- ***Dimension***: `Date`
- ***Metric***: `Order Total` (Aggregation: [SUM](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212))

**2) Daily `SKU` Count**

- ***Dimension***: `Date`
- ***Metric***: `SKU` (Aggregation: [COUNT](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583207))

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/aa0db0ed-3c3f-4a7f-948c-d5902a516c35) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Comment: thanks. unfortunately it's not correct. Let's take the date from27th. That would be two orders: 11 and 12. Order 11 has two line items (1 and 2). Order 12 only has 1 line item (1). Order 11 totals to 25.00 (both line items), Order 12 to 10. -> The total revenue for that day should be 35.00.

Comment: Updated the answer with the Metric set to `SKU Price`

Comment: didi a little fix, but this works. In my dataset there is also a quantity field that would (how many items per SKU). I added a calculated field. This is a nice workaround. The only information I would loose with this method is the shipping costs. They are included in the total costs, but not if I take the item_cost

Comment: Yes, a calculated field does the trick for the quantity. Regarding shipping costs, it may be possible....Could you elaborate? Is it a separate field - or the difference between values? Could you update the table in the question with the respective field / to clarify?

Comment: I have updated it. It would probably just be easier and more insightful to export the Shipping costs separatly.